# Append a picture between simultaneously appended elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insert

I have a JSON containing pictures URL, and would like to nest them in `<div>` that `.fadein()` only when the contained pictures are *completely* loaded.

I've been trying this with jQuery, allowing me to wait for an image to completely load *before* showing its parent.

```
$(img).load(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#resultList").append("<li id='li" + $(this).attr("id") + "'>");
    $(this).insertAfter("#li" + $(this).attr("id"));
    $("</li>").insertAfter(this);
    $(this).fadeIn();
}).attr({
    src: json.data[i].album.cover + "?size=big",
    id: "image" + json.data[i].picture.id,
    class: "imageResult"
});
```

Where this falls short is that I can't seem to insert the picture *between* the `<li>`. I've been trying to use a combination of `.insert`, `.insertAfter`, but the generated HTML always return something like this:

```
<ul id="resultList">
    <li id="li0001" ></li>
    <img src="myPicture.jpg" id="picture0001" class="imageResult">
</ul>
```

I'm fairly new to jQuery and have been mostly experimenting, this is the only problem I got stuck on for quite a moment. Would you kindly point out my mistakes and tell me how to insert this picture between, and not after, its parents ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you asking how to load an image between two DOM elements, or between two loading times? Or do you want the image inside the li tag?

Comment: Yeah, I want to add the loading picture between two DOM elements that are created when the picture is loaded. The `<li>` tag was just an arbitrary choice, it could have been a `<div>`, but considering that I'm manipulating JSON, a list made sense in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(img).load(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    var $li = $("<li/>").attr("id", "li" + $(this).attr("id"));
    $li.append($(this));           
    $("#resultList").append($li)        
    $(this).fadeIn();
}).attr({
    src: json.data[i].album.cover + "?size=big",
    id: "image" + json.data[i].picture.id,
    class: "imageResult"
});
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a bunch. I'm not sure I got the bigger picture about this problem but it sure solved it.

Comment: The bigger picture is you should eschew what I call "string programming", that is, playing with pieces of HTML as strings, appending them, etc. In your example it is manifested by appending open `<li>....`, than assuming `append` just adds mote contants and then by using `$("</li>").insertAfter(this);` closes it. This is "string programming". It does not work that way. jQuery always works with complete objects. The code in the answer eschews string programming and embraces working with objects (`$("<li/>")` creates closed li tag, then it is filled as an object and appended as an object).